# various checksums utilities precede hash with backslash

Tags: checksum

What is going on here?  A backslash in a directory name and/or file name seems to cause various checksum utilities to report the hash preceded with a backslash slash.

Note that the coreutil `wc` does not behave this way.

Behavior as expected:

```
#ppd# ls -1a
.
..
#ppd# mkdir a\\b
#ppd# ls -1
a\b
#ppd# for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i > a\\b/c$i; done

#ppd# ls -1 a\\b/c*
a\b/c1
a\b/c2
a\b/c3

#ppd# cat a\\b/c*
1
2
3

#ppd# wc --version
wc (GNU coreutils) 8.13
#pre# wc a\\b/c*
1 1 2 a\b/c1
1 1 2 a\b/c2
1 1 2 a\b/c3

#ppd# cd a\\b/

#ppd# md5sum --version
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.13

#ppd# md5sum c*
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  c1
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  c2
6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  c3
```

Now for the odd behavior:

```
#ppd# pwd
/home/abe/tdir/a\b

#ppd# md5sum ../a\\b/c*
\b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  ../a\\b/c1
\26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  ../a\\b/c2
\6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  ../a\\b/c3

#ppd# cd ..

#ppd# md5sum a\\b/c*
\b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  a\\b/c1
\26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  a\\b/c2
\6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  a\\b/c3

#ppd# sha1sum a\\b/c*
\e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e  a\\b/c1
\7448d8798a4380162d4b56f9b452e2f6f9e24e7a  a\\b/c2
\a3db5c13ff90a36963278c6a39e4ee3c22e2a436  a\\b/c3

#ppd# sha256sum a\\b/c*
\4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865  a\\b/c1
\53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  a\\b/c2
\1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  a\\b/c3
```

Backslash in filename:

```
#ppd# echo "4" > a\\b/c\\4
#ppd# ls -1 a\\b/*
a\b/c1
a\b/c2
a\b/c3
a\b/c\4

#ppd# md5sum a\\b/*
\b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  a\\b/c1
\26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  a\\b/c2
\6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  a\\b/c3
\48a24b70a0b376535542b996af517398  a\\b/c\\4

#ppd# cd a\\b/
#ppd# md5sum *
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  c1
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  c2
6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  c3
\48a24b70a0b376535542b996af517398  c\\4
```

I discovered the above when storing the hashes in xattrs as `ss=md5sum <filename>; setfattr -n user.cksm -v ${ss:0:32}`. Here are some of the  characters as reported by `getfattr -n user.cksm.md5` (the first line is just to aid in counting the characters, which ought to number 32 for an md5 hash:

```
#              123456789 123456789 123456789 12
user.cksm.md5="be28d5286d9c719a904550f41593d"
user.cksm.md5="a4e9e6958c9d5762dcf090871e44bf"
user.cksm.md5="#f39b8c4dc110178505c089cba7986"
user.cksm.md5="\\ebf1b8f8054d21c78f2a699776f84a0"
user.cksm.md5="+c2769ebdd2ce3a8355395d2129051"
user.cksm.md5="/9ac5b68efea0e9f02c917503cbb3e"
```

Answer (score 9):

<sup><sub>(Moved self-answer out of the question)</sub></sup>

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310401) to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23014), the answer is to the present question is rtfm:

> NOTE: The GNU sha digests documentation reference the md5sum digest documentation
>
> > For each file, ‘md5sum’ outputs by default, the MD5 checksum, a space, a flag indicating binary or text input mode, and the file name. Binary mode is indicated with ‘*’, text mode with ‘ ’ (space). Binary mode is the default on systems where it’s significant, otherwise text mode is the default. If file **contains a backslash** or newline, the line is started with a backslash, and each problematic character in the file name is escaped with a backslash, making the output unambiguous even in the presence of arbitrary file names. If file is omitted or specified as ‘-’, standard input is read.